# How to delete or replace text on monaco editor using testcafe?

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, testcafe, monaco-editor

I'm writing some tests with testcafe.
I have monaco editor field with some text, I want to delete the text and insert another text or just override the text that I have.
I tried this code and it inserts "someText" after the characters on the first line.
I used this line of code:

```
await t.typeText(Selector('.parent-class .inputarea'), someText);
```

any idea?

monaco before:

```
{
   "data": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2,
      "c": 3
   }
}
```

monaco after:

```
{{"data": { "newField": "text" }}
   "data": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2,
      "c": 3
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to interact with text in the [Monaco Editor Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) and it proved challenging indeed.

You can override the field's content by selecting it via `.pressKey('ctrl+a')` and then using `.typeText()` to type in new content.

```
fixture `monaco`
    .page `https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html`;

test('Monaco Ctrl+A', async t => {
    await t
        .switchToIframe(Selector('#runner'))
        .click(Selector('#container').find('.inputarea'))
        .pressKey('ctrl+a')
        .typeText(Selector('#container').find('.inputarea'), 'typetext');
});
```

You can use other [page actions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/interact-with-the-page.html) to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replace` option to override existing text:

`await t.typeText(Selector('.parent-class .inputarea'), someText, { replace: true });`

For more information, see [the typeText method](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/typetext.html#options).

Comment: I tried it, the monaco editor has a hidden input field.
I also tried to focus the filed and use ```await t.pressKey("backspace")```